# zsh attach to tmux by key binding

Tags: zsh, tmux, zshrc

I am trying to make *Alt-M* in zsh attach to a tmux session.

Content of .zshrc:

```
tmux-open() {
  tmux attach
}
zle -N tmux-open
bindkey '^[m' tmux-open
```

When I press *Alt-M*, instead of attaching to the tmux session, I get:

> open terminal failed: not a terminal

Calling `tmux-open` from the zsh prompt attaches to the tmux session. What is the problem with the key binding?

Answer (score 1):

This is caused by `zsh` purposely sestting stdin/out to `/dev/null`, see `man zlezsh:

> User-defined widgets, being implemented as shell functions, can execute       any  normal  shell  command.   They can also run other widgets (whether       built-in or user-defined) using the zle builtin command.  **The  standard       input  of the function is redirected from `/dev/null` to prevent external       commands from unintentionally blocking ZLE by reading from  the  terminal**,  ...

A solution, as [described here](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/512979/22339), is to restore the file descriptors back to `/dev/tty`:

```bash
tmux-open() {
    (
        exec </dev/tty
        exec <&1
        tmux attach
    )
}
```

Answer (score 0):

A possible alternative is to make a keybinding that just types the command `tmux attach`:

```
bindkey -s '^[m' 'tmux attach\n'
```

That will work when the prompt is on an empty command line

Comment: This unfortunately becomes much more difficult when `tmux` is to be run as a part of a more complex function.